# Less or More in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, mercurial, less, more

Is there a command in the Windows DOS prompt that is equivalent to the UNIX `less` or `more`?

Basically, the problem is that when I type `hg log`, the output has too many lines to fit on the screen and I want to paginate it.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: less: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/   it is part of the gnuwin32 set of ports for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Comment: what is wrong with the "more" command that has been a part of the command interpreter for as long as I can remember?  I am guessing DOS 5.x and Winnt 3.x AT LEAST and newer.  Did you even TRY to use the more command as you would in linux?? IT WORKS.

Answer (score 81):

Windows has the command `more`. [E.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_%28command%29#Microsoft_Windows) (Taken from Wikipedia)

> To display the file named letter.txt on the screen, the user can type either of the following two commands:

```
 more < letter.txt
 type letter.txt | more
```

So in your case you want `hg log | more`.

For heavier usage you will want something like [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), which have a more powerful `less` utility.

.
[image]

Comment: Yea, but the Windoze version only pauses the screen for a page at a time. You can't page up and down through the output. I've never used gow (mentioned in another reply) but I use UnxUtils every day. I love having grep, more, head, tail, sed, wc and other tools in Windoze.

Comment: @Tom: That is what `more` does on \*nix as well. `less` is the one with backwards scrolling support, as you've noticed.

Comment: Get less.  less is more.

Comment: unfortunately, `hg diff | less` and `hg diff | more` don't preserve color highlighting, so unlike with git, with hg one either has colorful text or scrolling... (tested on Win 10 x64, with `less` from UnxUtils, in cmd)

Answer (score 9):

On Windows 10, you can install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/):

> The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run Linux environments -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a virtual machine.

Once installed, start `bash.exe` and run `less /mnt/c/temp/test.txt` to open the file test.txt located in c:\temp.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer here!

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind installing additional software [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) is a nice toolkit with a set of standalone unix style tools that you can use, including less and more - it requires an install since it adds itself to path, but you can copy and use the install directory elsewhere as well.

Comment: This toolkit is epic!
less, grep, wget, curl, ssh, whereis.. and many more standard unix console tools, directly in windows CMD! and only 18MB..
windows CMD is now actually useful

Answer (score 4):

Up-to-date less build for Windows is here: http://adoxa.altervista.org/less/index.html

Comment: Thanks. `less` is a very important tool. Other implementation I have used suffer from the MSVCRT console I/O bug: https://yongweiwu.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/msvcrt-dll-console-io-bug/. This one is working well.

Comment: Thank God for that utils to be ported on windows, I feel much better now! :)

Answer (score 2):

I install a ready-to-run less via choco:

`choco install less`

https://chocolatey.org/packages/Less

It uses the binary generated by the aforementioned [less-Windows](https://github.com/jftuga/less-Windows/releases)

Comment: winget install jftuga.less

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find up-to-date less builds for Windows: https://github.com/jftuga/less-Windows/releases

This are the reccomended Windows builds on the [less official download page](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used UnxUtils for many years. In most recent installations, I just use the [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) which embeds mingw-based utilities. It installs all same commands than UnxUtils and also includes compression utilities variants like `zcat`, `zless`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a recent version of Windows and have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installed, you can run Linux's `less` directly from CMD:

```
wsl less "my file.txt"
```

File paths must be expressed in terms of the WSL filesystem:

```
wsl less "/mnt/c/Users/coejoder/Documents/my file.txt"
```

Or converted using `wslpath` in a subshell:

```
wsl less "$(wslpath "C:\Users\coejoder\Documents\my file.txt")"
```