# The closest thing to 'less -S' using pre-installed Windows command-line tools?

Tags: windows, command-line, less

What would be the best way to chop long lines of output (and do some horizontal scrolling perhaps, but I'm not holding my breath) on Windows, using Windows command-line tools like `more`. I want to simulate the `less -S` pager.

Comment: I should've added "existing/preinstalled" (DOS command-line tools). I know that `less` is available on Windows, but that is not installed by default no? WSL is also not installed by default, if I understand correctly.

Comment: And I also should've written "Win32 DOS command prompt".

Comment: WSL is installed by default. Follow the link in my answer if you want to enable WSL and use that way.

Comment: So WSL is installed by default, but not enabled by default? When not yet enabled, is `less` et al available?

Comment: No, only `more`. Are you limited in what you can install/enable for some reason? If you're used to Unix command-line tools you will enjoy having them under Windows, and there's no down-side as far as I know. [Here are some more examples and links](https://superuser.com/questions/426226/less-or-more-in-windows/426229) if you need them.

Comment: I am providing an automatic paging option (`--page`) to my CLI script which outputs potentially wide text table. `more` is pretty much useless here. It would be nice if the script can do this without user having to install another program.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you can use most or all of the Unix-like tools on a Windows machine.

See [the GNU page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) for information and download links.

That is the DOS command-line tools you need!

I'm not sure where I installed mine from, as they are bundled with other things like git for Windows. I will try and add a better link but you should be able to find one if the GNU page doesn't have a direct Windows download.

**EDIT** It seems the commands are also now included in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which is a Windows component you can enable. There's [a page here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-linux-commands-on-windows-10/) with info about how to enable WSL if you want to do it that way.

**EDIT 2** The above assumes a Windows environment, but that may be an incorrect assumption. If you want to do this literally under DOS, there were thinks like the MKS Toollkit that did the same thing, which you might want to try and get hold of.

Comment: The bad news is that those are all Win32 programs and won't run on MS-DOS...

Comment: @user1686 True, but I'm assuming the OP means under Windows--but I may be quite wrong. We will see.

Comment: Regarding the Git installer, I *think* it bundles the "msys" distribution (which is somehow related to MinGW compiler suite).

Comment: @RegEdit yes, I meant under Windows.